# Как конвертировать строку в число с ОО-языках ?

Tags: c#, java, c++

Доброго всем ! Как конвертировать строку String str = "789" в int ? При этом не используя методы такие как Parse.Int(str) (Java) или аналогичный в "Шарпе" ?
Если у кого то сохранился примерчик с универа буду рада посмотреть !
Спасибо ...

Comment: 7*10^2 + 8*10^1 + 9*10^0

Comment: @Flammable, благодарю, вот только что значит этот значёк: ^ ?

Comment: возведение в степень. или можно писать так: `10e2`, где цифра после `e` - степень.

Comment: Только сейчас пришло в голову.

--

Возможно основная проблема у ТС в *преобразовании очередного символа* в цифру (число)?

Для кодировки ASCII (по сути мы все сейчас работаем с ней) это очень просто:

     d -= '0'; // вычитаем из кода цифры код нуля

IMHO прошло уже достаточно времени и немного подскажу. Основной цикл преобразования получается таким

     long d, s = 0;
     while (isdigit(d = str[i++)) {
       long p = s;  // это для "отлова" переполнения
       s = s * 10 + (d - '0');
       // дальше сами 
     }
     // а тут вспомним о знаке числа, который надо анализировать раньше

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Писать код не буду (и мне честно говоря несколько лень, и вам полезнее реализовать самой). 
Возьмем "обычный" случай, когда из строки нужно получить вещественное число в десятичной форме записи. То есть отбросим варианты парсинга строк, представляющих числа в экспоненциальной форме и в различных системах счисления, отличных от десятичной.

1) Изначально стоит проверить, может ли из строки быть получено число. Для этого должны быть соблюдены следующие условия:

1. строка не может содержать ничего, кроме символов цифр, знака "минус" и десятичной точки (либо запятой в качестве разделителя целой и дробной части).
2. Минус и точка могут встречаться только один раз.
3. Минус может быть только первым символом, а точка не может быть ни первым, ни последним (варианты типа ".5" корректными числами не являются. Хотя это по желанию)
4. Точка не может идти сразу за минусом
5. Число не может состоять только из минуса (по сути и только из точки тоже, но это   избыточное условие, так как  в этом случае нарушится правило 3)
6. Можно добавить ограничение на разрядность числа. Скажем, строка "1234567890987654321" не может быть распарсена в int, так как данное число мало в какой int влезет (уж точно не в шарповский).
7. При желании можно еще разрешить пробельные символы в начале и/или конце строки

Все вышесказанное словоблудие вообще-то можно завернуть в какую-нибудь хитрую(или не очень хитрую) регулярку, но я с ними к сожалению даже не на "вы"

2) Разбить строку на целую и дробную части по десятичной точке. Если ее нет, то дробная часть отсутствует

3) Целую часть читать в цикле посимвольно справа налево, символ-цифру на степень десяти примерно так: "123" => 10^0 * 3 + 10^1 * 2 + 10^2 * 1 => 3 + 20 + 100 => 123

4) Дробную часть (если она есть) наоборот читать слева направо, умножая на степень одной десятой примерно так: "0.123" => 1 * 0.1^1 + 2 * 0.1^2 + 3 * 0.1^3 => 0.1 + 0.02 + 0.03 => 0.123

Не уверен, что алгоритм полностью корректен, но в общем и целом - примерно так

З.Ы. Учитывая, что в вопросе говрится о конвертации в int, алгоритм существенно упрощается за отсутствием необходимости искать дробную часть

Comment: Добавлю, что проверки на "правильность" числа обычно совмещаются с его посимвольным преобразованием.

Одно из возможных описаний структуры чисел (в БНФ(?) и "картинкой") можно посмотреть [здесь](http://json.org/).

Comment: не проще попробовать преобразовать в Double и отловить исключение?

Comment: >не проще попробовать преобразовать в Double и отловить исключение?

проще. Но в условии говорилось: 

> При этом не используя методы такие как Parse.Int(str) 

То есть требовалось написать собственный парсер без привлечения сторонних средств парсинга

Comment: тогда, действительно, лучше регулярные выражения

Comment: @vinger4, а пример с регулярками (и отлавливанием переполнения, а также разумной диагностикой ошибок в записи числа) сможете написать?

Comment: @vinger4 тогда регулярку в студию. Я хотя бы честно признался, что не владею ими на достаточном уровне.

Answer (score 2):

Это как раз тот случай когда применим мем [Use the source Luke](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Use+the+Source+Luke). Посмотрите на исходник `Integer.parseInt()`

[фтыкаем и вкуриваем](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "789";
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(str);
```

Comment: Это скрытый парсер - не совсем то, чего хотел топикстартёр. Минусую.